# Cross Domain API call on mobile

Tags: android, cordova, cross-domain

I am getting following error on mobile while trying to make cross domain call

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://domain1.com. Origin http://domain2.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Is there any workaround for the same?

Comment: do you set this on config.xml  <access origin="*"/>

Comment: yes it did not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using jsonp, that's the only way around  http://json-p.org/ , http://blog.edwards-research.com/2012/10/cross-domain-ajax-a-simple-workaround/ , 
or make sure that on server side cross domain policy file is present and changed accordingly http://hub.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-a-guide-to-cross-domain-policy-files--active-3832
quite simply just allow access from all and test.

However the best way would be is to use jsonp